# Как узнать, включено ли одно дерево в другое?

Tags: python-3.x, дерево

Я хотел бы создать alogritmo, который позволяет мне сказать, если дерево включено в другое. Благодаря [этому сайту](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-binary-tree-is-subtree-of-another-binary-tree/) мне удалось разработать алгоритм, который позволяет мне знать бинарные деревья, но я хотел бы обобщить его.

> *When did Beyonce start becoming popular?*

Я сделал это со следующим кодом: `treeQuestion[0]`:

```
[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 
'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']),
'?_._punct'])]
```

Мы можем нарисовать дерево следующим образом:

```
>>>questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
>>>treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
>>>print(treeQuestion)
When did Beyonce start becoming popular?
[to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print()  for sent in en_nlp(predicted.iloc[0,3]).sents]

>>>treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
>>>print(treeQuestion)
[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]
          start              
  __________|___________      
 |    |     |     |  becoming
 |    |     |     |     |     
When did Beyonce  ?  popular
```

И я хотел бы знать, содержится ли она в следующем дереве и в какой степени это показано:

```
--- 1 ---
born and raised in houston, texas, she performed in various singing and dancing competitions as a child, and rose to fame in the late 1990s as lead singer of r&b girl-group destiny's child.
[Tree('performed_VBD_ROOT', [Tree('born_VBN_advcl', ['and_CC_cc', Tree('raised_VBN_conj', [Tree('in_IN_prep', [Tree('houston_NN_pobj', [',_,_punct'])]), 'texas_NN_npadvmod'])]), ',_,_punct', 'she_PRP_nsubj', Tree('in_IN_prep', [Tree('competitions_NNS_pobj', ['various_JJ_amod', Tree('singing_NN_nmod', ['and_CC_cc', 'dancing_NN_conj'])])]), Tree('as_IN_prep', [Tree('child_NN_pobj', ['a_DT_det'])]), ',_,_punct', 'and_CC_cc', Tree('rose_VBD_conj', [Tree('to_IN_prep', ['fame_NN_pobj']), Tree('in_IN_prep', [Tree('1990s_NNS_pobj', ['the_DT_det', 'late_JJ_amod'])]), Tree('as_IN_prep', [Tree('singer_NN_pobj', ['lead_JJ_compound', Tree('of_IN_prep', ['r&b_NN_punct', Tree('child_NN_pobj', [Tree('destiny_NN_poss', [Tree('group_NN_compound', ['girl_NN_compound', '-_HYPH_punct']), "'s_POS_case"])])])])])]), '._._punct'])]
                                                      performed                                                                                  
  ________________________________________________________|__________________________________________________                                     
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |                       rose                                 
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |     ___________________|_________                           
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |                   as                        
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |                   |                          
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |                 singer                      
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |          _________|_____                     
 |   |   |   |   |       born                             |                         |    |         |         |               of                  
 |   |   |   |   |    ____|_____                          |                         |    |         |         |     __________|_____               
 |   |   |   |   |   |        raised                      in                        |    |         |         |    |              child           
 |   |   |   |   |   |     _____|_______                  |                         |    |         |         |    |                |              
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |             in           competitions                   as   |         in        |    |             destiny          
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |             |        _________|__________               |    |         |         |    |     ___________|______        
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |          houston    |                 singing         child  to      1990s       |    |    |                group    
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |             |       |          __________|_______       |    |     ____|____     |    |    |            ______|____   
 ,  she  ,  and  .  and texas           ,    various     and              dancing   a   fame the       late lead r&b   's         girl
```

На самом деле, как можно видеть, мы можем найти `rose to fame`, который очень похож на `start becoming popular`. Что касается половины (3/6) дерева, здесь можно сказать, что показано 50%.

#### Ожидаемый результат

Например:

```
>>># создание первого дерева
>>>text = start becoming popular
>>>textSpacy = spacy_nlp(text1)
>>>treeText = nltk_spacy_tree(textSpacy)
>>>t = WordTree(treeText[0])

>>># создание второго дерева
>>>question = When did Beyonce start becoming popular?
>>>questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
>>>treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
>>>q = WordTree(treeQuestion[0])

>>># сравнение деревьев
>>>isSubtree(t,q)
True
```

---

## Моя попытка

Я нашел способ узнать, когда одна фраза содержится в другом. **Я оставляю вопрос открытым, если вы можете сказать мне, когда одно дерево похоже на другое. В частности, *синонимы* или *отсутствующие слова*.** Например,

- `rose to fame` для `start becoming popular`
- `start being popular` для `start becoming popular`

#### Класс, который преобразует список в дерево.

```
class WordTree:
    '''Дерево для массива синтаксического анализа зависимости spaCy'''
    def __init__(self, tree, is_subtree=False):
        """
        Construct a new 'WordTree' object.

        :param array: Массив, содержащий зависимость
        :param parent: Родитель массива if существует
        :return: ничего не возвращает
        """
        self.parent = []
        self.children = []
        self.data = tree.label().split('_')[0] # первый элемент дерева # Мы также добавим синонимы.

        for subtree in tree:
            if type(subtree) == Tree:
                # Итерации по глубине поддерева.
                t = WordTree(subtree, True)
                t.parent=tree.label().split('_')[0]
            elif type(subtree) == str:
                surface_form = subtree.split('_')[0]
                self.children.append(surface_form)
```

#### Функция, которая проверяет, содержится ли дерево в другом

```
def isSubtree(T,S):
'''
функция сказать, если два дерева одинаковы
'''
    if S is None:
        return True
    if T is None:
        return False
    if areIdentical(T, S):
        return True
    return any(isSubtree(c, S) for c in T.children)

def areIdentical(root1, root2):
    '''
    функцию сказать, если два корня одинаковы
    '''
    if root1 is None and root2 is None:
        return True
    if root1 is None or root2 is None:
        return False

    # Проверьте, являются ли данные обоих корней и их детей одинаковыми
    return (root1.data == root2.data and
            ((areIdentical(child1 , child2))
             for child1, child2 in zip(root1.children, root2.children)))
```

#### пример

```
# создание первого дерева
text = "start becoming popular"
textSpacy = spacy_nlp(text)
treeText = nltk_spacy_tree(textSpacy)
t = WordTree(treeText[0])

# создание второго дерева
question = "When did Beyonce start becoming popular?"
questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
q = WordTree(treeQuestion[0])

# сравнение деревьев
isSubtree(t,q)
```

Здесь мы тестируем два дерева из двух предложений, где один является частью другого. У нас тогда есть `True`. Может быть интересно найти способ сказать, когда он частично содержится в другом.

#### Цель сравнения дерева

Это будет использоваться для сравнения дерева вопросов S с несколькими деревьями ответов T_i. Если T_i подобен S, то он с большей вероятностью будет содержать ответ.

Comment: В чём Ваша проблема? Вы хотите разработать алгоритм. Что Вам мешает это сделать?

Comment: @hedgehogues Да, но я хотел бы обобщить и получить помощь. Вот почему я задал вопрос. Особенно в тех случаях, когда слова отсутствуют или слова являются синонимами.

Comment: @jfs Да, это правда. Это основной случай, но также хорошо. Я обновил. Если S NONE удара, он обязательно включен. Если T NONE, я помещаю FALSE, но это обсуждается.
- В связи с вопросом: _Что вы понимаете под "дерево включено в другое"_ я добавил графическое представление деревьев из spaCy. Сначала это было строгое включение. Теперь я хочу знать, сколько дерева S представлено в T, то есть даже если ему не хватает слов или имеет похожие слова.

Comment: @ThePassenger неясно, что подразумевается под "Теперь я хочу знать, сколько дерева S представлено в T, то есть даже если ему не хватает слов или имеет похожие слова". Насколько я понял, вы хотите знать, в какой степени включено одно дерево в другое. Но здесь нужно указать, что конкретно Вы за этим ставите. В противном случае, решение может оказаться неадекватным

Comment: @hedgehogues Да! Это точно, и это точно проблема. Я бы сказал, что `S` похож на `T`, если в `T` есть элементы `S`. Это, пожалуй, самый наивный подход, но, возможно, неплохо начать.

Comment: Для того, чтобы ответить на Ваш вопрос, мне нужно понять, зачем Вам нужно такое сравнение. Могли бы Вы разъяснить, зачем Вам такое сравнение. Расскажите, где и как это будет использоваться (добавьте правку в вопрос)